# Getting error on Nop Commerce application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am getting error like

> An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'UsaEpayService'.
>
> Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
>   Getting above exception on Resolve -
>   Path : Libraries\Nop.Core\Infrastructure\DependencyManagement\ContainerManager.cs

Here is my code:

```
 public virtual object Resolve(Type type, ILifetimeScope scope = null)
        {
            if (scope == null)
            {
                //no scope specified
                scope = Scope();
            }
            return scope.Resolve(type);
        }
```

I have [cross-posted this here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/46891/getting-error-on-nop-commerce.aspx).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You hit a copy+paste tripwire as well, so I have declared the cross-posting for you. Please _always_ declare your cross-posting. (Please edit your duplicate to point to here as well).

Comment: seems you are using a payment plugin for usaepay, and it seems that autofac fails when it invokes the usaepay service, can you provide the code for your constructor inside your usaepayservice?